# Not within Jobscope - Aggravated injury

Tags: communication, singapore

**Bio**

1. Working as a data science consultant
2. Sustained a back injury during my military service (with medical documentation)

**Background**

I have been asked to work until 1-2am for a week performing physical labor, lifting of boxes to support a client project despite having sounded out my medical condition. Due to a lack of manpower, we juniors (I'm one of them) had to abandon our daily tasks to support this effort.

During that week, I took a day off with a medical certificate due to my aggravated back condition. Upon returning back to work, I was sent back to the client place with the same exact physical tasks as the project is still ongoing.

During my less than half a year of working in this company, this is my first non-job scope related task.

**Solution**

How should I handle future occurrences of such events?

Comment: What is MC? None of the 30 or so suggestions I could find fit.

Comment: Oops it means 'Medical Certificate'

Comment: Why would a company take what are presumably well-paid staff (even "junior" data scientists are rare enough) and have them waste their time doing monkey-work? Particularly a consultant?

Comment: Assuming your fellow juniors are also well-paid specialists, I'm tempted to suggest you all club together, subcontract a team of professional fitters through your local equivalent of http://checkatrade.com for a fraction of what you're all being paid for the week, and spend the time and the difference on a beach holiday while the fitters do the physical work better and faster than you could...

Comment: "monkey-work"? Unnecessary. Don't shame honest work.

Comment: @user1666620 because the job needed doing, and it needed doing now.  I have carried boxes of equipment from one place to another before, because they needed moving.  It's cheaper getting a few existing employees to do it, even senior ones, than to go through the process of hiring temporary people just to move a few boxes.

Comment: @MattMalone yes, it is honest work - but it is unskilled labour which can and should be done by others for a fraction of the cost.

Comment: @SimonB I suggest you and your bosses look up "opportunity cost". Instead of creating value for the company, you became quite possibly the world's most expensive box-carrier. Whoever put you up to it ought to be fired.

Comment: @Javier: I took the liberty of copy-editing your question, and expanded the "MC". Please re-edit as appropriate.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to workplace.SE! While your question is not bad, it would help if you could explain _what your goal is _. Simply asking "What should I do?" / "How should I handle this?" does not work well here. Instead, explain what you want, e.g. "How can I avoid this work in the future?", or "How can I request better accomodation?", etc.

Comment: Related: [Can my boss make me do manual labor if my job description is as the Office Manager?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/111621/can-my-boss-make-me-do-manual-labor-if-my-job-description-is-as-the-office-manag/111623)

Answer (score 69):

Tell them how it is. You provided your medical documents up front, they should not be making you do such tasks.

Tell them that you are not going to do the tasks to avoid chronic injury. You have the official documents to support this.

If they say otherwise then talk to HR. They're not going to risk such a thing due to a lack of manpower.

Comment: the lack of manpower especially will get worse if you prevent a data scientist from working for weeks or months for a task which an untrained external person could have done for a small amount of money.

Comment: I would add that they are risking a lawsuit if further injury occurs, and certainly facing Workman's Comp claims.

Comment: I'd say you don't even need a medical history for that sort of task to injure you permanently. "*I'm a data scientist, I'm neither trained nor equiped to do heavy lifting*" should be sufficient reason.

Comment: @AmiralPatate The question doesn't state that the lifting is heavier than a regular person can do, and training to lift things that a regular person can lift only takes a few minutes. So, really, the medical certificate is crucial, here.

Comment: @DavidRicherby To be fair, odds are the job has no strength or endurance requirements for lifting.  An hour a day of physical labour could definitely be an issue for some workers, even without a specific medical condition.  Although most people could likely do it, it seems pretty far outside of the scope you might expect for the role.

Comment: @DavidRicherby OP called it "physical labor" and mentioned lifting boxes "till 1-2am for a week", so I interpreted that as heavy lifting. The sticking point really isn't so much the mass of individual boxes as it is the nature of the job, which sounds like a movers' job and not an office worker's one.

Comment: @AmiralPatate "Physical labour" just means that it's work involving the body rather than the mind. Anyway, trying to second-guess exactly what's going on is irrelevant to the question. The asker has a medical condition and that means that _they_ shouldn't be doing this work regardless of whether their hypothetical twin who doesn't have a medical condition could do it.

Comment: Does it really matter? Heavy lifting or not, the OP is not required to do it. Data scientist or labourer, medical note says to avoid it.

Comment: @DavidRicherby The underlying point is that, however you call it, it wasn't described as a job you can reasonably ask of any office worker, and that `Tell them that you are not going to do the tasks to avoid chronic injury` should apply regardless of medical condition.