# Painter being forced to do remodel work

Tags: united-states, legal, job-description

I was hired 3 years ago by a local painting contractor. Recently my employer started remodeling his **own** house and this is where the work is taking place.

I am now being required to do the following tasks that have nothing to do with painting; siding, roofing, framing, building decks, drywall, interior trim including cabinetry and more.

I am experienced in these fields but was hired specifically as a painter.

My boss is not a general contractor, is only licensed and bonded to paint.

Is this legal? Can I say no? I was threatened with being fired for not wanting to perform these duties.

If the company is only licensed and bonded to paint, is it legal for them to perform this type of work, regardless of the location? I understand it is HIS home but he isn't doing the work, I am and I work for a painting company.

Comment: What does your employment contract say?  Does it have the standard "and other duties as assigned" clause?

Comment: You tagged this [US]. Do you work in an at-will-state? If your boss can legally fire your literally "at will", there is really nothing you can do about this.

Comment: If you’re getting paid to do work that builds valuable skills outside your current domain knowledge, why are you upset? i assume your employer also knows this, and accepts the quality of work you’re outputting…i fail to see the problem.

Comment: My reasoning for not wanting to do the work is that it is much more physically demanding, I have had multiple back surgeries and I have told them this type of work hurts my back and my surgeon told me to avoid it.

Comment: I am not under any contract, and I believe my state is an at-will state.

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I am in the process.

Comment: @matt. - You should determine if your state is an at-will employment state or not and edit your question

Comment: @matt. Do you have any documentation from your surgeon requiring you to avoid this kind of work?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can my boss make me do manual labor if my job description is as the Office Manager?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/111621/can-my-boss-make-me-do-manual-labor-if-my-job-description-is-as-the-office-manag)

Comment: @nvoigt It is not legal to fire someone for refusing the break the law in the United States. So this really does depend on whether the OP doing this work without a license/bond is legal.

Comment: @matt. you mention your back surgery, and elsewhere that your brother *owns* the company. What did your brother say when you spoke to him about not being comfortable doing the job?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[At-Will Employment](https://www.ncsl.org/research/labor-and-employment/at-will-employment-overview.aspx) has [three major exceptions](https://www.bls.gov/opub/mlr/2001/01/art1full.pdf), one of which is the public policy exception:

> Under the public-policy exception to employment at will, an employee is wrongfully discharged when the termination is against an explicit, well-established public policy of the State. For example, in most States, an employer cannot terminate an employee for filing a workers’ compensation claim after being injured on the job, or for refusing to break the law at the request of the employer. The majority view among States is that public policy may be found in either a State constitution, statute, or administrative rule, but some States have either restricted or expanded the doctrine beyond this bound. The public-policy exception is the most widely accepted exception, recognized in 43 of the 50 States.

An employer cannot legally fire you for refusing to break the law under the public policy exception. You can look up which states don't have the public policy exception in the linked PDF.

> If the company is only licensed and bonded to paint, is it legal for them to perform this type of work, regardless of the location?

You should be able to look up which jobs/professions require a license on the site for your state/local government (because this varies by state). You might find the [The National Occupational Licensing Database](https://www.ncsl.org/research/labor-and-employment/occupational-licensing-statute-database.aspx) useful as well. (Do note that the table on the page itself may not be complete for your state.)

Answer (score 6):

> Is this legal?

Yes.

> Can I say no?

Yes.
With some employers, this is the equivalent of saying "Please fire me."

> I understand it is HIS home but he isn't doing the work, I am and I
> work for a painting company.

You work for HIS company. If what you are being asked to do doesn't suit you, find a new employer. In most US locales, there are plenty of employers looking for workers.

In a comment, you mentioned that your employer is your brother. Instead of asking "is this legal", you should just sit down and discuss it with your brother.

Comment: How is it legal when his license is for painting only?

Comment: So why would they need a license to paint and not one for other trades? That's a bit confusing. I'm already looking for new employment I just want to know how this all works for future reference.

Comment: I get that, but he isn't doing the work. I am

Comment: @matt. Are you sure that, despite being adamant about only painting, you know the company's legal status better than the owner?

Comment: @ComicSansSeraphim Yes, I do. My brother owns the company.  Do you think you know it better than I do?

Comment: @JoeStrazzere I didn't think it was relevant. As messed up as it is.

Comment: Asking my brother does nothing.  That's why I came here, which was equally as helpful.

Comment: One word answers like "Yes" are super informative. Keep up the good work.

Comment: @matt. Would you prefer, "yes, Matt, this is legally permitted under US and state law. It is not illegal."

Comment: @ComicSansSeraphim OP is looking for "None of the additional tasks you mentioned, (siding, roofing, framing, building decks, drywall, interior trim including cabinetry) require a license or bond.". Probably with a source proving it.

Answer (score 3):

> Can I say no? I was threatened with being fired for not wanting to perform these duties.

If you don't want to do the work, quit. No point waiting to be fired. Find alternative employment first if you can. These are tough times.

I'm not taking sides, but as a personal observation many employers are doing something a bit different just to keep their employees busy and justify paying them these days while their business is short on work due to COVID related issues in the industry. No one minds much if the work isn't too onerous, they're just happy to have a payday. So I see dancers doing gardening and service staff doing make work, airhostesses answering phones etc,.

Comment: “These are tough times” LOL! In America? Quite the opposite. Demand for home-improvement workers is *vastly* outstripping supply. Contractors are booked solid for months. Still always wise to find a new position before quitting, but doing so should be easy.

Comment: Ok, I'm not familiar with the USA, huge unemployment in my locale.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how you have many options here. The business owner is having you work on his own home. There's likely nothing likely illegal about that. You work in an "at-will" state. There's likely no actual legally binding employment contract stating what your job duties are and aren't. You can do the work and get paid or you can leave and find employment elsewhere. Unfortunate as that seems, those are likely your only options.

Answer (score 1):

Only membership in a trade union lets members say "that's not my job."  You consider yourself a painter.  Your boss considers you an employee.  Your boss does get to decide these things.

If you want future employment to be only painting, consider joining the IUPAT, but depending on where you live this might limit the work you can get.

Answer (score -1):

> I was hired 3 years ago by a local painting contractor. Recently my
> employer started remodeling his own house and this is where the work
> is taking place.

This is interesting. If he is doing the work at his own house ...

> siding, roofing, framing, building decks, drywall, interior trim
> including cabinetry and more.

The building of decks is something that local governments watch carefully. If it is done wrong then people can die. Of course if the work you were being asked to do is gas, electrical, and water then the building inspector will want to make sure everything is up to code.

Even if you aren't doing the electrical the boss could be having a carpet layer do that.

> Is this legal?

Maybe. People do DIY projects in their own homes all the time. The work has to be done by licensed insured people for only a small subset of a big project.

I also assume that if the work requires building permits and inspections then those have been done.

Now if you are asking can you be forced to do this....

> Can I say no? I was threatened with being fired for not wanting to
> perform these duties.

That depends on the contract you have. There are examples when the "boss" requires employees or sub-contractors to do a little favor at no cost to keep the work flowing to the employee. But if you aren't getting paid that is a problem.

Also if your boss isn't the owner, then owner might not know this work is being done and your pay is being miss-charged to another project.

But if the work is legitimate and the boss is paying for the work, and you are getting paid the proper amount then most people don't see a problem.

If you have a contract and can pick and choose which projects you might be able to skip this one. But you still put that contract at risk.

I guess you as an employee could say no. But if there is no other projects you can switch to, then you might see a smaller paycheck or find your self unemployed.

Answer (score -6):

A goof up will wreck his license.  The client pays **him**, not you.  Unless you are committing a criminal act, your boss is the only one liable if something goes wrong with the job.

I am not an attorney.

Comment: The work is at the company owners house.